# Ember Checkbox getting name of element in callback

Tags: ember.js

If I define a checkbox as follows:

```
  {{input type="checkbox" name="email" checked=controller.isEmailChecked}} Email
```

In the callback `controller.isEmailedChecked`, defined as:

```
isEmailChecked: function(key, value) {
 ...
}
```

How do I get the value of `name` ("email")?

My controller is responsible for displaying multiple checkboxes so I do not want to have to write lines like this:

```
  {{input type="checkbox" name="x" checked=controller.isXChecked}} X
  {{input type="checkbox" name="y" checked=controller.isYChecked}} Y
```

Only to be doing:

```
ixXChecked: function(key, value) {
  // Set or Get
  this.set('x', value);
  this.get('x');
}
ixYChecked: function(key, value) {
  // Set or Get
  this.set('y', value);
  this.get('y');
}
```

Can someone point me to the docs please.

**Edit:** Same applies to actions on Buttons:

```
        <button {{action 'toggleSetting'}}>
        </button>
```

How would I get the name of the element in the `toggleSetting` callback?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to a action like this: `{{action "post" "test"}}` where the second test can also be a variable. `{{action "post" mail}}`

As for the checkboxes I'd solve that with an item controller:

```
{{#each thing in things itemController='thing'}}
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=onChecked}}
{{/each}}
```

and your controller would looks something like:

```
App.ThingController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['parent'] //where parent is the name of your other controller.
  action: {
    isChecked: function() {
      this.get('contollers.parent')
          .send('checkboxChecked', this.get('model.name'));
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can add a component, lets call it `named-checkbox`. And that would look something like this:

Template (app/templates/components/named-checkbox.hbs):

```
{{input name=name type="checkbox" checked=onChecked}}
{{yield}}
```

Component (app/components/named-checkbox.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/named-checkbox';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout: layout,
  name: "",
  action: {
    onChecked: function() {
      this.sendAction(this.get('action'), this.get('name'));
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
{{named-component name="email" action=isChecked}}
```

This will result in the `isChecked` action being called on the controller with the name as it's attribute:

```
actions: {
  isChecked: function(name) {
    this.set('name', !this.get('name'))
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be even cleaner if you use a component I'll update my answer later to include a component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks albertjan but this is more simple:

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding=someModelProperty}}
```

It updates the `someModelProperty` when clicked, and it also sets the correct value initially.

Comment: accessing views via the global scope is deprecated since ember 1.8. see: http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/ and there is also the whole action down data up. http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/ It may be easier but I can't guarantee it will still work in ember 2.0

Comment: I don't see why the action thing is an issue: I am not using your approach of a custom component. The `checkedBinding` simply gets the value from the controller (model). Point taken about the deprecation issue. Thanks.